# Failed to flatten XML for resource

Tags: android

I have this issue when building app

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>
> .../app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:831:4: Failed to flatten XML
> for resource 'activity_cancel_membership_limit1000' with error:
> Attempting to flatten xml with unfinished spans.
>
> .../app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:831:4:
> string/activity_cancel_membership_limit1000 does not contain a valid
> string resource.
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

Where

```
   <string name="activity_cancel"><Data><![CDATA[Press to<font color='#D13F57'> Cancel</font>]]></Data></string>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: remove `<Data>` and `</Data>` and replace `'` with `"`

Comment: @Selvin You saved my day. FYI, replacing ' with " is enough. I kept <Data> and </Data>

Comment: In my case, it was because I had CDATA with "it's" instead of "it\'s"